# How to clear a label in qt creator

Tags: c++, string, qt, label, qt-creator

this is the first time i write in this site, I'm trying approach me at Qt-creator but I've a problem:
I want to delete the text of the label when the user click a button, i've tried some solution but without success

this is the code:

```
struct finestra{
float costo;
int altezza;
int larghezza;
QString text;
QString costoStr;
};

float Totale=0;
finestra vet[21];
int i=1;

//SOME CODE

 Totale+=vet[i].costo;
 vet[i].costoStr = QString::number(vet[i].costo);
 vet[i].text = vet[i-1].text + "Finestra ad un anta bianca <br>" + "€" + vet[i].costoStr +"<br>";
 ui->TotaleFinestre->setText(QString(vet[i].text));
 i++;
```

I've tried with this function:

```
void preventivi::on_pushButton_clicked()
{
   ui->TotaleFinestre->clear();
}
```

if someone know how to do please answer,

**thanks to all** and sorry for my bad english.

Comment: Have you checked if the slot is called using a debugger or a simple debug output? How do you make the connection? If the example code is from an UI file, maybe you have renamed "pushButton", then the connection is broken...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As QLabel define the slot `void QLabel::clear()`, you can also just connect this slot with the clicked() signal that will be emitted after a click on your pushButton, using the `QObject::connect` method :

`QObject::connect(pointer_to_your_pushButton, SIGNAL(clicked()), pointer_to_your_label, SLOT(clear()));`

**EDIT  :** Here is a small example

The UI is a QWidget that has a QLabel and a QPushButton. I did that with Qt Designer but it doesn't matter here.

```
#include "widget.h"
#include "ui_widget.h"

Widget::Widget(QWidget *parent) :
    QWidget(parent),
    ui(new Ui::Widget)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
    QObject::connect(ui->pushButton, SIGNAL(clicked()), ui->label, SLOT(clear()));
}

Widget::~Widget()
{
    delete ui;
}
```

You can even do that using "Edit Signals/Slots" inside Qt Designer and make the signal/slot connection between your widgets. ( you won't need to manually call the previous QObject::connect, as it will be done automatically inside the `Ui_Widget` class, generated by the uic)

[image]

Or you can do all without Qt Designer, it's up to you. 
Hope this helps.

Comment: Can you be more specific?

Comment: I have edited my answer to be more specific with a working example. However, i suggest you to read http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/signalsandslots.html

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you should try

```
void preventivi::on_pushButton_clicked()
{
    ui->TotaleFinestre->setText("");
}
```